# Need Regex to validate 11-digit phone number without plus sign

Tags: regex

I need a regex to validate phone number without plus (+) sign for example

46123456789,46-123-456-789,46-123-456-789

number should be 11 digit rest of should ignore

i am currently using this Regex `/([+]?\d{1,2}[.-\s]?)?(\d{3}[.-]?){2}\d{4}/g`

its not correct at all

Comment: Why not just remove the non-digit characters from the string then validate what's left is 11 characters long

Comment: I need to also validate 46-123-456-789 no plus sign in it

Comment: Exactly what my previous comment will achieve

Comment: Like `^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}|\d{11}$` https://regex101.com/r/Ed4qJJ/1 This page has more info on validating phonenumbers  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex

Comment: You can use `/^[+]?(\d[^\d]*){11}$/g` http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5eb4109275622d7659040000

Comment: @Thefourthbird i didnt need "+" sign your regex is fine but its allowing plus (+) sign

Comment: @UmerZaman I don't think it is allowing a + sign due to the anchors `^` and `$` See https://regex101.com/r/Jhtnq5/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird its allowing in this case "+46123456789" not for this "+46-123-456-789"

Comment: @UmerZaman You are right, I am sorry I forgot the grouping around it `^(?:\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}|\d{11})$` https://regex101.com/r/E1VGfK/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks buddy that's correct can you post in answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the pattern you tried:

Using this part in your pattern `[+]?` optionally matches a plus sign. It is wrapped in an optional group `([+]?\d{1,2}[.-\s]?)?` possibly also matching 12 digits in total.

The character class `[.-\s]` matches 1 of the listed characters, allowing for mixed delimiters like `333-333.3333`

You are not using anchors, and can also possible get partial matches.

---

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` to match either the pattern with the hyphens and digits or match only 11 digits.

```
^(?:\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}|\d{11})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}` Match either the number of digits separated by a hyphen
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{11}` Match 11 digits
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E1VGfK/1)

If you want multiple delimiters which have to be consistent, you could use a capturing group with a backreference `\1`

```
^(?:\d{2}([-.])\d{3}\1\d{3}\1\d{3}|\d{11})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uLS9b9/1)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is the input looks like. But based on your question I supposed you want to trim it and match it with regex?

trim your input.

```
string.split(/[^0-9.]/).join('');
```

and you can match it with this regex:

```
((\([0-9]{3}\))|[0-9]{3})[\s\-]?[\0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have this function return true or false and use as is.

```js
function isPhoneValid(phone) {
  let onlyNumbers = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  if (onlyNumbers.length != 11) console.log(phone + ' is invalid');
  else console.log(phone + ' is valid');
}

isPhoneValid('1 (888) 555-1234');
isPhoneValid('(888) 555-1234');
```